# "Class X" OR "X Class"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

A. I will sit in class X.

B. I will sit in X class.

Question:
Any specific reason for using "B" format?

Answer (score 2):

If 'X' is an [attributive noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) (a.k.a. Noun Adjunct), then you need to use the 'B' format:

> I will sit in math class.

Answer (score 1):

I am sitting in first class, is ordinal. 
I am sitting in class one, is cardinal.